# Programatic logic for nested if statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Trying to rewrite some code that was very repetitive into some kind of loop, and figuring out the logic is frying my brain somewhat.

The original code looked a bit like this:

```
if(a){
    if(b == "foo1"){
        if($('#foo2').val() == a || $('#foo3').val() == a || $('#foo4').val() == a || $('#foo5').val() == a || $('#foo6').val() == a){
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
if(a){
    if(b == "foo2"){
        if($('#foo1').val() == a || $('#foo3').val() == a || $('#foo4').val() == a || $('#foo5').val() == a || $('#foo6').val() == a){
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
if(a){
    if(b == "foo3"){
        if($('#foo1').val() == a || $('#foo2').val() == a || $('#foo4').val() == a || $('#foo5').val() == a || $('#foo6').val() == a){
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
if(a){
    if(b == "foo4"){
        if($('#foo1').val() == a || $('#foo2').val() == a || $('#foo3').val() == a || $('#foo5').val() == a || $('#foo6').val() == a){
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
 if(b == "foo5"){
        if($('#foo1').val() == a || $('#foo2').val() == a || $('#foo3').val() == a || $('#foo4').val() == a || $('#foo6').val() == a){
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
if(b == "foo6"){
        if($('#foo1').val() == a || $('#foo2').val() == a || $('#foo3').val() == a || $('#foo4').val() == a || $('#foo5').val() == a){
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
```

I want to rewrite this into a loop (or loops), but am struggling to get the logic right.

So far, I have this:

```
if (a){
    for (i=0; i < 6; i++){
        var fieldNames =[ "foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4", "foo5", "foo6"]
        console.log("i loop "+ fieldNames[i]);
        if(b == fieldNames[i]){
            for (j = 1; j < fieldNames.length; j++){
                if($('#'+fieldNames[j]).val() == a){
                     //do something here
                     }
                  }
               }
         }
    }
```

I know this isn't right, but can anyone help me with what the logic should be?

Thanks

**Edit:**

Should clarify what the variables refer to.

This function is called inline from a  element on the onblur event with the line `doCheck(this.value, 'foo1')` (this example relates to just the first instance of that, the b input is foo2 for the second and foo3 for the third and so on...

The full function looks like this:

```
function doCheck(a,b)
  if (a){
    for (i=0; i < 6; i++){
    var fieldNames =[ "foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4", "foo5", "foo6"]
    console.log("i loop "+ fieldNames[i]);
    if(b == fieldNames[i]){
        for (j = 1; j < fieldNames.length; j++){
            if($('#'+fieldNames[j]).val() == a){
                 //do something here
                 }
              }
           }
     }
  }
}
```

So the variable `a` is the value of whatever is in the select element and the `b` variable is the field name.

Comment: Try writing out a table with the various conditions you need to handle; trying to parse them from your code is frying my brain, too.

Comment: I'll give that a go, but to briefly explain, the whole thing should loop through six field names. Whatever is in the outer condition `if(b == foo1)` should not be included in the loop of the same six field names in the nested condition. So, in this instance if the outer condition looks at foo1, then inner conditions look at foo2 - foo6. If the outer looks at foo2, then the inner ones look at foo1 - foo6 excluding foo2. Hope that explains it. Will try and do the table still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could produce a list of possible fields, remove `b` from that list, then compare against the remaining ones.

```
if (a) {
    var fieldNames = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5', 'foo6'];
    // Remove b from the fields
    fieldNames.splice(fieldNames.indexOf(b), 1);
    var doSomething = fieldNames.reduce(function(prev, fieldName) {
        return prev && $('#' + fieldName).val() === a;
    }, true);
    if (doSomething) {
      // do something
    }
}
```

Another way of looking at this would be something like this:

```
if (a) {
  var fieldNames = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5', 'foo6'];
  // Remove b from the fields
  fieldNames.splice(fieldNames.indexOf(b), 1);
  var doSomething = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
    if ($('#' + fieldNames[i]).val() !== a) {
      doSomething = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (doSomething) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your problem shall be here :

```
if($('#fieldNames[j]').val() == a){
```

Repalce with :

```
if($('#' + fieldNames[j]).val() == a){
```

Moreover, your loop may be updated like that,

```
 var fieldNames =[ "foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4", "foo5", "foo6"];
// Define fieldNames before the first loop
if (a){
    for (i=0; i < fieldNames.length; i++){
        console.log("i loop "+ fieldNames[i]);
        if(b == fieldNames[i]){
            for (j = 1; j < fieldNames.length; j++){ // WHY YOU START AT j=1 ? I shall start at j=0 in my opinion
                if($('#fieldNames[j]').val() == a){
                     //do something here

                     break; // <=== EXIT 2nd LOOP IF YOU FIND SOMETHING
                     }
                  }
               }
               break; // <=== EXIT 1st LOOP IF YOU FIND SOMETHING
         }
    }
```

Comment: Ooops, yes that was a mistake, but I was asking more about what the logic should be to get it to loop through the array in the correct manner. Will edit that mistake now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want the `//do something here` to be the same for all if blocks in the original code. If you want the same then you can make the loop as you suggest, otherwise not.

Why not put the values i.e. `$('#foo2').val()` into an array and test for a and b using the `indexOf()` function on the array?

```
var fieldValues =[ $("#foo1").val(), $("#foo2").val(), etc];
if(fieldValues.indexOf(a)!=-1 || fieldValues.indexOf(b)!=-1){
    //do something here
}
```